# plain XeTeX bold font does NOT work for tibetan fonts

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, tibetan

I am using Plain XeTeX to typeset some Tibetan books. But found that the /B option of \font didn't give me the bold version of that font. I did noticed some English fonts have a standalone version of bold font, but the tibetan font available to me do not have one. The MS Word can change the tibetan texts to bold font easily. Have tried a lot of different font like: SambhotaDege, Jomohari, ctrc-uchen, Monlam Uni OuChan2, none of them in the \font command makes differences between with and without /B option. Any suggestions?

```
\font\Him='Microsoft Himalaya:script=tibt;+abvs;+blws' at 22pt
\font\HimB='Microsoft Himalaya/B:script=tibt;+abvs;+blws' at 22pt

\def\ex{
དཀར་མཛེས་ཨ་ཡིག་ལས་འཁྲུངས་ཡེ་ཤེས་གཏེར།།
ཕས་རྒོལ་ཝ་སྐྱེས་ཟིལ་གནོན་གདུང་ལྔ་བཞིན།།
ཆགས་ཐོགས་ཀུན་བྲལ་མཚུངས་མེད་འཇམ་དབྱངས་མཐུས།།
མ་ཧཱ་མཁས་པའི་གཙོ་བོ་ཉིད་གྱུར་ཅིག།}
\Him \ex \ex \ex

\HimB \ex \ex \ex

\vfil\bye
```

---

[image: one sample page.]Here's one sample page from the project that we are working on, to show our gratefulness. Sorry it is not very clear, cause my notebook have a lot resolution.

Comment: Your code *does* work for *Noto Serif Tibetan*, which makes me think that *Microsoft Himalaya* does not have a bold variant. This is confirmed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/microsoft-himalaya). (It likely only appears to work in MS Word because Word simulates a bold weight if it isn't available.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the problem is because *Microsoft Himalaya* has no bold font file. It's only available in regular weight. This is confirmed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/microsoft-himalaya).

It works in Word, because Word simulates a bold weight if it's not available (without telling you).

You have two options.

The better option is to switch to a different font which is available in a bold weight, e.g., *Noto Serif Tibetan*.

Alternatively, you can do do something similar to what Word does and simulate a bold weight. This is not really a great idea though, since the result will always be sub-optimal.

Compare the real bold and fake bold in the following example. You can control the amount of thickening with the `embolden` option.

```
\font\Him='Noto Serif Tibetan:script=tibt;+abvs;+blws' at 22pt
\font\HimB='Noto Serif Tibetan/B:script=tibt;+abvs;+blws' at 22pt
\font\HimFakeB='Noto Serif Tibetan:embolden=4,script=tibt;+abvs;+blws' at 22pt

\def\ex{
དཀར་མཛེས་ཨ་ཡིག་ལས་འཁྲུངས་ཡེ་ཤེས་གཏེར།།
ཕས་རྒོལ་ཝ་སྐྱེས་ཟིལ་གནོན་གདུང་ལྔ་བཞིན།།
ཆགས་ཐོགས་ཀུན་བྲལ་མཚུངས་མེད་འཇམ་དབྱངས་མཐུས།།
མ་ཧཱ་མཁས་པའི་གཙོ་བོ་ཉིད་གྱུར་ཅིག།}
\Him \ex

\HimB \ex

\HimFakeB \ex

\vfil\bye
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanx for your great answer. Would you pls give the TeX code of the sub-optimal solution together? Cause our co-workers stick to the Tibetan fonts without bold variant.

Comment: @user227842, The `\HimFakeB` is the suboptimal solution. Just use your Microsoft don't instead of Noto Serif Tibetan.

Comment: I mean Microsoft font (not don't)

Comment: Thanx a lot. We've got all that we want. Here is a sample page of our work, it is  the Tibetan means to say thank you.